# is there a formula (or something) that i can use to get information from the same row that a formula gets its answer from

Tags: excel, excel-2010, formulas

I have 2 work sheets. One where the raw data is entered and one that is a summary page.
It tracks scores in 4 sporting events with the student name and school name.
I have the rank of their score so I can get 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc even with ties and no skipping over the rank number if there is a tie so you see 1,2,2,3,4....  I have the top 7 scores go to the summary page for each event.  What I need to do is take the name of the student and the school, and bring it with their score to the summary page.  I have limited skill in excel 2010 (that is what I am using. No skill what so ever in VBA or sql or any of that type of coding.  I am hoping there is a formula that will allow me to get the school and name of the student from the area where the score came from.  I hope I'm not too confusing with this.

Raw data page would look something like this where we enter the names of the schools competing, the name of the student and the scores they get.

```
The ABC School
mary Smith        8.50
Jane white        7.60

The Awesome School
Jane Doe          9.52
Betty May         8.50
```

The summary page would be the rank in the first column, the school in the 2nd column, the student name in the 3rd column and the score in the 5th column.  It's the `School` and `Student Name` I can't get into the columns:

```
Rank     School                 Student name         Score**
1        The Awesome School     Jane Doe             9.52
2        The Awesome School     Betty May            8.50
2        The ABC School         Mary Smith           8.50
3        The ABC School         Jane White           7.60
```

I have also used "names" for ranges of formulas so a big range for event #1 might be called "Event1" so it was easier to do my other formulas.

I need the formulas you may come up with explained a bit as I am no expert when it comes to formulas and can get confused when it gets long.

Comment: There are too many students and scores to consider getting the rank on the raw data page.  I just need the top 7  in each of the 4 events that is why there is a summary page to begin with.  I'm thinking there must be a way to determine the cell address where a formula got its answer from.  The formula to get the scores on the summary page is Large("Score",1)  Where "score" is the name of all the cells in the range that hold the score and the #1 is changed to a 2, then a 3, then a 4 and so on up to 7.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without a pivot table but rather with a formula that will update automatically based on the raw data. I know that is a great way to do it but there will be others using this and may not have any excel skills beyond entering in the raw data and printing up the summary page.  So I really do need a formula type thing to try and get this done.

Comment: I have a formula that equates rank to the scores.                   =IF($D6="","",SUMPRODUCT(($D$6:$D$12>$D6)/COUNTIF($D$6:$D$12,$D$6:$D$12&""))+1)

Comment: Yes but if there was a tie it skipped a rank number and we can't have it skip a number so the above formula fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the second table in you post, you can build a pivot table.

Your data looks like this:

[image]

Click anywhere within that table and then click Insert > Pivot table. Select to show the pivot table on a new sheet or in the existing sheet.

In the Pivot Table panel that appears on the right of the window,

- select and drag **School** to the rows panel
- then drag **Student name** to the rows panel
- then drag **Score** to the values panel

[image]

The pivot table will then look like this:

[image]

This is the result you asked for in your question. You can fine-tune the display and data in the pivot table. There are hundreds of articles and tutorials about Pivot Tables on the Internet.

Comment: I believe the first table is what the OP has, and the second table is what OP is trying to get as result.

Comment: Punts not sure what you mean by "cheating"

Comment: I'm thinking some type of IF statement with Index and Match use in the statement or some type of Lookup statement so it can look left. but can't seem to get the arguments right.

Comment: I'm trying to get the school and student name to fill in on the 2nd table (the results page) I can get everything else to fill in but that.